# Programatic zoom in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Using the code pattern [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957), I want to programmatically achieve semantic zooming (in or out).  I'm unsure how to get the proper x, y, and scaleExtent terms that are augmented via the zoom:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));
```

See JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u0moj7ez/). The zoomIn and zoomOut functions should simulate the mousewheel events centered in the SVG.

Here's a solution based on the answer below: http://jsbin.com/dociwuvacu/1

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you have provided is not sufficient to be able to understand and answer your question.

Comment: I want to be able to simulate mousewheel down/up in the center of the plot, such that you could click a button to zoom in or out.  Is that clear?

Comment: Please give a jsfiddle.

Comment: I've added a JS fiddle -- let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I successfully updated your fiddle, but in case not, here is the type of code you would need:

```
function zoomIn() {    
    zoomer.scale(zoomer.scale()+.1);
    zoomer.event(svg);
}

function zoomOut() {
    zoomer.scale(zoomer.scale()-.1);
    zoomer.event(svg);
}
```